# LSTM Model for Multivariate Multi-Series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-modeling, lstm

I'm looking to create an LSTM model to predict a certain label trained on multiple short-time series data. How would I go about doing this? Each time series has 10-30 time steps and 20 different features. I want to train on all these so that given a one-time step the model can predict a certain label. How would I also deal with large amounts of missing data? Thank you!